# Mountain Lion: can no longer change certificate trust

Tags: macos

Following the update to Mountain lion, I can no longer "trust" a certificate associated with my JNLP file.  This worked previously. Following going through the "trust" dialogue, the next screen is still stuck on "deny" as the only option.  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Same here. Very frustrating - I've followed all the steps to include the offending certificate in Keychain Access but in the end am only left with one option - Deny.